# Proving vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V = C^0([a,b])$ be the vector space of continuous functions $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that

$S=\lbrace f(x) \in C^0 [a,b] \vert \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=0\rbrace$

is a subspace of $V$.

What I tried:

I thought of using the fundamental theorem of calculus to get f(b) = 0 and then trying to add to generic elements of S to get that they are also elements of S and then do the same with scalar multiplication, but I do not know if this is a sufficient test i.e. f(a)+f(b) = 0 $\in S$ and then something similar with scalar multiplication. Ideas?

Comment: Hint: Use definition of subspace. Notice how the set $S$ is defined.

Comment: @Mahbub Alam I know you have to first prove S is a subset of V and then prove that + and scalar multiplication produces an element in S but my question is how to prove that + and scalar * produce an element in S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f,g$ from $S$, so $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx=0$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)~dx=0$, so $\int_{a}^{b} (f+g)(x)~dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx + \int_{a}^{b} g(x)~dx=0$

And $\int_{a}^{b} c \cdot f(x)~dx = c \cdot \int_{a}^{b} f(x)~dx =0$, for any $c$ in $\Bbb R$.

So, $cf, f+g$ are in $S$.

Comment: Nice, thorough solution!